# sudo apt-get update not working could not lock

Tags: apt

When I use the command `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Whats the meaning of this?

Answer (score 2):

seems like your apt is locked with another process. you can view which process is using apt with this command:

```
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

to unlock it run this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

some Apt process is running on. You first need to close it.

use this command to see if there is any apt processors running:-

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

if you found it then u can kill it with its PID

```
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to see what is using the lock

```
jorion@home{~}:$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
synaptic 7061 root   20uW  REG   8,54        0 131016 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

in this example its synaptic

Answer (score -2):

Try this command to  abort apt-get process:

> killall apt

May can help if other app used apt. after this command may you get some error to run apt again, if is, so run:

> apt update -f